# Image won't show when wrapped in stackpane (tornadoFX)

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'm trying to create a field of grass and some cows on it. 
Using a list of ones and zeros to decide which boxes are supposed to have a cow on it. And then I use flowpane to create my grid. When I try to add the image of a cow to a stackpane it doesn't show.

here is the relevant code:

```
    override val root = flowpane {
    this.setPrefSize(viewWidth * tileSize, viewHeight * tileSize)
        //imageview("/cow.jpg")
        for (i in hage) {
            stackpane {
                rectangle {
                    fill = GREEN
                    width = tileSize
                    height = tileSize
                    arcWidth = 5.0
                    arcHeight = 5.0
                    if (i == 1) {
                        /*circle {
                          fill = RED
                          radius = 10.0
                      }*/
                        imageview("/cow.jpg")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The out-commented image before the loop/stackpane shows (if it's not out-commented) and the stackpane works how I want it to if cows are represented as circles.

So how come the image isn't showing?

Answer (score 0):

You're adding your `ImageView` to the `Rectangle`, not the `StackPane`. The `Rectangle` is a shape that doesn't render/support children. Try moving it outside of the `rectangle {}` block :)

Comment: Happy to help :)